# `position` column in database, how to re-order?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
id | name | position
1    Bob     4
2    Jim     5
3    Harry   73
4    Paul    89
```

I want the user to be able to re-order the columns as they see fit, like move one row up and down, using the `position` column.  I have thrown in the big numbers in there (73 and 89) just to cater for all events.

Is there a way to dynamically re-order the table via SQL? Or will I have to manually re-order all tables when someone selects 'move up' on 'Harry'? I can only imagine I will have to:

1. Find the ID before Harry's (in this case '2')
2. Move all ID's (including '2's) up by one.
3. Set Harry's position to to '2'.

There must be a quicker easier way to do this using MySQL/PHP?

Comment: When you change the order javascript usually sends back the PK and new position so you can easily update everything in one query. Something like `{"order":[5,6,2,1,3]}`. Then you update everything.. there's no seeking for what changed or shuffling things around. Just reset all the row's position.

Comment: @Chud37 -can you provide some more information?

Comment: @MikeB, I am not using javascript, but PHP.

Comment: @Chud37 Same difference. Get the order in its entirety instead of trying to move things around piece mail. You'll run into all kinds of problems if you simply try to "swap the third and forth items" if that's all that's changed.

Comment: @FathahRehmanP, I just want people to order the rows by themselves, by clicking up and down arrows. I dont want to fiddle with the PK, so I created a new column called `position`.   However I am trying to find a quick and susinct way of re-order all the values when someone wants to move a row upwards/downwards.

Comment: @Chud37 - can you provide position order after pressing each up or down. That is if current position is 4,5,73,89, suppose user selected 89 and pressed up. In that case can you provide 4,5,89,73 to query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that find this page in the future, I found some code from an old shop that did the trick:

```
if((isset($_POST['moveup_x'])) || (isset($_POST['movedown_x']))) {
$current = select("SELECT `position` FROM `events` WHERE `id`='".rEsc($eventid)."';", true,true);

    if(isset($_POST['moveup_x'])) $target = ($current - 1); 
    if(isset($_POST['movedown_x'])) $target = ($current + 1); 

    if($current > 1) {
        $counter = 1;
        foreach(select("SELECT `id` FROM `events` ORDER BY `position`;") as $val) 
        {
            $newposition = $counter;
            if($current == $newposition) {
                $newposition = $target;     
            } elseif(($current > $newposition) && ($target <= $newposition)) {
                $newposition++;
            } elseif(($current < $newposition) && ($target >= $newposition)) {
                $newposition--;
            }
            runSQL("UPDATE `events` SET `position`='{$newposition}' WHERE `id`='{$val['id']}';");
            $counter++;
        }
        array_push($msgs,"Successfully moved event.");
    } else {
        array_push($msgs,"!Cannot move the event any higher up the list.");
    }
}
```

You need to know your current, which you can get from $_POST (in this case I got from rowID in the database) and your target (I had img submit buttons so I just minused or plussed from whichever button the user clicks).  Once you have that, loop through each row in the table however you see fit, (set a counter beforehand) and run the IF/ELSE statement.  Modify for your need.

It works very well though.  There problably is a quicker/easier way, i.e. all in one SQL statement, instead of updating every single row in the database, but I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 1):

If can you provide position order after pressing each up or down you can use following query. That is if current position is 4,5,73,89, suppose user selected 89 and pressed up. In that case if you can provide 4,5,89,73 to query then following query will help you

```
select * from table22 order by field(position,4,5,89,73);
```

Comment: But this doesnt actually re-order the table, just the results I get.  I want to actually change the value in `position`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use a simple case in your update statement, see example below for moving a number up. For moving a numberdown, same case with minor adjustment, and you can use a nested case to decide which to use by comparing number and destination

```
set @nr=4; set @dest=2;
select *,

case 
when number between  @dest and @nr-1 then number+1
when number=@nr then @dest
else number
end as number_alt

 from
(
select 1 as number  union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
)a
```

Comment: Oh! This is quite beyond my SQL abilities, but I will give it a go.

Comment: sql is super easy, don't get discouraged! it's very verbal comtrol flow

Comment: So I suppose I would replace 'number' with 'position', but there is nowhere stating which table I would be referencing?